# Is it possible to send Upstream Message with Java?

Tags: java, firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have my own app server which communicate with FCM server. And I have Android/iOS mobile apps working well.

I want to set a third party program using Java which send a message to FCM server repeatedly so I can keep tracking my own app server is working fine.

I tried to find a solution but official website mention about upstream message only with Android/iOS app.

Is it possible to send a upstream message to FCM server using Java? 
(Or any other good idea to monitor the server? I faced the server sometimes goes down for some reason without notice it :( )

Comment: By server, do you mean the FCM server or your own app server?

Comment: oh, I meant my own app server which communicate FCM server.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to send upstream messaging other than what is shown in the docs -- currently available for Android and iOS.

Even if you are able to send an upstream message, it wouldn't make sense. The flow of upstream messaging is:

```
Client App > FCM Server > App Server
```

So the result/response that you would get when sending a message, should it succeed/fail, will point out the communication between the FCM server and the Client App, *not* with the App Server.